# Generate "behaving abnormally" questions?

Tags: discussion

In response to the [comment by @keshlam](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/how-can-we-improve-the-off-topic-closing-reasons#comment4765_2123) and the [recent question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/12402) I am wondering if maybe we should have one or a couple of generic questions along the line of "My pet is behaving abnormally, what should I do?" With an answer along the lines of "Go to the vet ASAP, the behaviors A, B & C are indicative of possible serious issue.  Your pet needs to see a trained Vet to rule out possible serious issues before seeking answers online."

We could vote to mark questions as dupe of the the "behaving abnormally" Q&A, if/when the pet has seen the vet, the OP edits the question on why it is not a vet issue and we provided answers.

Maybe the question is written by an expert on that type of pet, so we can get a good foundation of all the behaviors that specific to that species (cats, dogs, rabbits, etc)

Comment: I have provided generic yes and no answers below for your voting ease.  or post your own answer...

Answer (score 3):

Without a specific issue in mind, I'm not sure if it's possible to write any "general" questions about abnormal behaviour that isn't going to be considered too broad technically.

I think the underlying issue here is that the current user group doesn't want to answer any type of medical questions, and some of the previous meta discussions (especially: [Should medical emergencies always be off-topic?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/798/should-medical-emergencies-always-be-off-topic)) might need to be revisited.

Comment: I partially agree, I know we have had two users in the last couple of months answering medical question, who claimed or implied they were Vets.  While there is no requirement to validate your level of experience the answers appeared to me to represent Vet level answers.

Comment: are you able to undelete this https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/a/792/6796 please. It is a valid answer and I'm hoping to revisit this issue

Answer (score 2):

With cats, any unexplained behavior change may call for a trip to the vet, as they will almost always try to hide discomfort. (With the exception of hairballs.)

With other animals... it sounds like you are looking for a pet first aid reference. Which is a fine thing, but other sites have addressed this better than we can here.

Comment: I agree, but for other species its safe to assume that *my adult dog started chewing my underwear and wont stop trying to get to them* and *my dog started having spasms all of the sudden* are **two different** types of abnormal behavior. So maybe only instances similar to the second situation could be marked as the dupe of this (suggested) new canon question

Answer (score -2):

**Yes**, great idea.  Why didn't we think of this sooner?

Answer (score -3):

**NO** This is a terrible idea! See my comment on why.